# What does the PIC mnemonic MOVFP do?

Tags: assembly, pic

I enjoy programming in Microchip PIC assembly language, and I want to use a library routine that has the instruction MOVFP in it, on a PIC that does not have this instruction. I cannot find any documentation that explains this, the best I can find is an unexplained reference to "Peripheral register file address", so my question is: please what do MOVFP and MOVPF do, and how can I implement them in an instruction set that does not include them?

Comment: Looks like a short version of memory->memory move: http://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/uP/_contents/Microchip/17CXX_instr/movfp.htm

Comment: Thank you @dbrank0 for a prompt and complete answer -- your reference explains it nicely. I now see that it is the equivalent of MOVF f,0 followed by MOVWF f. So, with restrictions on the highest addresses for p and f, it saves one instruction on PICs that have it,